# Grammatical number agreement: "We detected particles with a distinct envelope and a dense internal part"

Tags: grammatical-number

It is okay to mix the grammatical number thus in a complex sentence? "Particles" are plural, but they have (based on the available data obtained using electron microscopy) a singular "part" and a singular "envelope":

> In the intercellular space and on the surface of about 5% of the cells we detected spherical **viral particles** 100-120 nm in diameter with an electron-dense internal **part** and a distinct **envelope** with "spikes" about 10 nm in length.

Or should one to use a word like **each** to avoid this number mix-up:

> In the intercellular space and on the surface of about 5% of the cells we detected spherical **viral particles** 100-120 nm in diameter, **each** with an electron-dense internal **part** and a distinct **envelope** with "spikes" about 10 nm in length.

Comment: The prepositional phrase is understood to apply to each member of the set of identified particles. Not a problem. If you used plurals (envelopes, internal parts) there would be an ambiguity -- does each particle have more than one internal part and more than one envelope?  **each** is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Each" makes it more clear, but anyone reading would understand that "each" is meant even if not stated.  This is not a case comparable to "the cats is hungry".